# java check if digits in square of a number are not in its cube

Tags: java, arrays

Define a positive number to be isolated if none of the digits in its square are in its cube. For example 69 is n isolated number because 163*163 =  26569  and 163*163*163 = 4330747 and the square does not contain any of the digits 0, 3, 4 and 7 which are the digits used in the cube. On the other hand 162 is not an isolated number because 162*162=26244 and 162*162*162 = 4251528 and the digits 2 and 4 which appear in the square are also in the cube.

Write a function named isIsolated that returns 1 if its argument is an isolated number,  it returns 0 if its not an isolated number and it returns -1 if it cannot determine whether it is isolated or not.

I have tried this:

```
public static int isIsolated (int n) {
        int square = n*n;
        int cube   = n*n*n;
        int[] a = new int[7];
        int[] b = new int[7];

        if(n < 2097151 || n>1){         
            for(int i=6;i>=0;i--){
                int k = square % 10;
                int l = cube % 10;

                a[i]= k;
                b[j]=l;

                square = square/10; 
                cube = cube/10;
            }

            for(int j=a.length-1;j>=0;j++)
            {
                for(int m=0;m<j;m++)
                {
                    if(a[j] == b[m])
                        return 0;
                    else
                        return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

but its not working as expected.

I am a beginner pls help me.

Comment: What do you expect? Please give an example that goes against your expectation.

Comment: isIsolated (162) returns 1

Comment: Another question: do all of the digits of the square have to be in the digits of the quad? Or is it sufficient if only one is contained?

Comment: your `j` loop is wrong anyways. you'er doing `j=7 ; j>= 0; j++`, so testing a[j], a[j+1], a[j+2]`, etc.. e.g. you're running off the end of the array.

Comment: You are using a variable 'j' in first for loop. Where is it defined ?

Comment: isIsolated(162) returns 0 for me. Only thing I had to change was b[j] =l line.. This should be b[i]=l

Comment: Also note that `if(n < 2097151 || n>1){` probably should be `if(n < 2097151 && n>1){`

Comment: oh yah sorry thats 163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a number of issues with your code.

You were putting `0` in the array once the number was exhausted so any number with less than 7 digits would end up with at least one `0` in teh array and fail your test.

You were leaving the default `0` in the array so any number with a `0` in either it's square or it's cube would have gone wrong. This code suggests the highest isolated number whose cube will fit into a `long` is:

> 31563 is isolated - ^2 = 996222969 ^3 = 31443785570547

```
// Max digits.
private static final int DIGITS = 20;
// Indicates an empty digit.
private static final int EMPTY = -1;
// Max value I can handle.
private static final long MAX = (long) Math.cbrt(Long.MAX_VALUE);

public static int isIsolated(long n) {

    if (n > 1 && n < MAX) {
        long square = n * n;
        long cube = n * n * n;
        long[] a = new long[DIGITS];
        Arrays.fill(a, EMPTY);
        long[] b = new long[DIGITS];
        Arrays.fill(b, EMPTY);
        for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++) {
            if (square > 0) {
                a[i] = square % 10;
                square = square / 10;
            }
            if (cube > 0) {
                b[i] = cube % 10;
                cube = cube / 10;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++) {
            if (a[i] != EMPTY) {
                for (int j = 0; j < DIGITS; j++) {
                    if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

public void test(int n) {
    System.out.println(n + " is " + (isIsolated(n) == 1 ? "" : "not ") + "isolated");
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    test(1234);
    test(69);
    test(162);
    for (long i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        if (isIsolated(i) == 1) {
            System.out.println(i + " is isolated - ^2 = " + (i * i) + " ^3 = " + (i * i * i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @oldcurmudgeon, its working as expected but I cannot use inbuilt utilities ex. Arrays.fill(a, EMPTY), please suggest me some plain array function....

Comment: @Anish - I think you can work out how to achieve the same as `Arrays.fill` without my help.

Answer (score 1):

`for(int j=a.length-1;j>=0;j++)`

Try doing `j--` here instead of `j++`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine this will contribute to the problem:

```
for(int j=a.length-1;j>=0;j++)
{
    for(int m=0;m<j;m++)
    {
        if(a[j] == b[m])
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

The return statements inside the `if ... else ...` will stop the function after 1 iteration, whether a match is found or not. The `return 1;` should be moved outside of both `for` loops. The function will then stop if a match is found, but carry on to check the whole contents of the arrays if no matches are found:

```
for(int j=a.length-1;j>=0;j--) // edit: also change this to j-- as mentioned by Peter
{
    for(int m=0;m<j;m++)
    {
        if(a[j] == b[m])
            return 0;
    }
}
return 1;
```

Comment: returning 0 in every case

Comment: No, only returning 0 if the two `int`s are equal and the number is therefore not isolated.

Comment: isIsolated(2) is returning 0 but its isolated number 2*2 = 4 and 2*2*2=8

Answer (score 0):

Your using Java so why not use some the tools that come with it.

I would generate two strings of decimals one from both square and cube values using Integer.toString(value)

Then walk the first string putting all the digit characters in a java.util.Set of characters.

Then walk the second string checking if each digit character is in the Set and return the failure case if it is, and return success if you reach the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int isIsolated(long n){
    long square = n*n;
    long cube = n*n*n;
    long temp_square = 0;
    long rem_cube = 0, rem_square = 0;
//The maximum positive number that can be
//represented as a long is 63 bits long
    if(n < 2097151 && n > 1){
        while(cube != 0){
            rem_cube = cube % 10;
            cube /= 10;
            temp_square = square;
            while(temp_square != 0){
                rem_square = temp_square % 10;
                temp_square /= 10;
                if(rem_cube == rem_square)
                    return 0;
            }
        }
    return 1;
    }
return -1;    
}
```